# How do I sed only matched grep line

Tags: shell, unix, sed, grep, sh

I want to replace a variable only if two other variables matches. For Example I have this in my data.txt:

```
Mary Jane:Runs:Pasta
Mary Jane:Kicks:Apricot
John:Runs:Pasta
```

And I want to replace one variable only on the line which matches with both value. Say I want the first variable to match "Mary Jane" and the second to match "Runs" and then change that particular line from "Runs" to "Sleep", so this should be the result:

```
Mary Jane:Sleeps:Pasta
Mary Jane:Kicks:Apricot
John:Runs:Pasta
```

But I get this instead:

```
Mary Jane:Sleeps:Pasta
Mary Jane:Kicks:Apricot
John:Sleeps:Pasta
```

Comment: It really sounds like you're just asking for `sed 's/Mary Jane:Runs/Mary Jane:Sleeps/`. But there must surely be more to it than that, no?

Comment: Yes I think your answer would be more relevant as I was thinking of something like     `sed "s/$VAR1:$VAR2/$VAR1:$NEW_VAR/"`. Thanks!

Comment: Trying to build on the `sed 's/Mary Jane:Runs/Mary Jane:Sleeps/` approach becomes ugly when the requirements change to be something like `first field is A and either 13th field is B or 27th field is C` which in awk would trivially be `$1=="A" && ($13=="B" || $27=="C")` and if you want to add in `the third occurrence of...` for example then just forget about it. For anything beyond simple substitutions on single lines you should just use awk for clarity, simplicity, portability, efficiency, extensibility and most other desirable attributes of software.

Comment: Ahh, Thanks for the explaination Ed. I've got a better understanding on why awk is used instead now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two solutions. One using `sed` and another using `awk`.  Both makes use of the shell variables `who` and `what` (these helps us find the line(s) that needs changing).

```
who="Mary Jane"                                  
what="Runs"                                      

sed "s/^$who:$what:/$who:Sleeps:/" data.in

awk -vwho="$who" -vwhat="$what" -F':' \
  'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $1 == who && $2 == what { $2 = "Sleeps" } 1' data.in
```

The `sed` example makes use of double quotes to get the shell to expand the variables in the substitution command, while the `awk` example transfers the values of the shell variables into the Awk script by means of assigning them to Awk variables on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

You should really use awk, not sed, for that:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} ($1=="Mary Jane") && ($2=="Runs"){$2="Sleeps"} 1' file
```