# Using shell variables in gensub in Awk

Tags: awk, sed

I tried to answer a question asked here

[How do I sed only matched grep line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41657716/how-do-i-sed-only-matched-grep-line/)

as below

```
 awk -F":" -v M="Mary Jane" -v A="Runs" -v S="Sleeps" '{OFS=":" ; print gensub(/(M):(A)/,"\\1;S","g")}'
```

but it did not work so I am guessing gensub is not able to recognize the shell variables M, A and S passed to awk , Is there a way to use shell variables in gensub in awk ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're experiencing is not because you're using `gensub()`, it's to do with regexps. There are regexp literals, e.g. `$0~/foo/`, and then there are dynamic regexps which are strings that are converted to regexps when they are evaluated, e.g. `$0~"foo"` or `{var="foo"} $0~var`. If you want to use a variable in **ANY** regexp context then you need a dynamic regexp and so that is the syntax you need to use, not the regexp literal syntax. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps.

The correct syntax for what you wrote would be:

```
awk -F":" -v M="Mary Jane" -v A="Runs" -v S="Sleeps" '{OFS=":" ; print gensub("("M"):"A,"\\1;"S,"g")}'
```

but that has some semantic issues (e.g. partial matches and setting OFS for every line instead of once when it's never even used and almost certainly unnecessarily using `"g"` instead of `1` and why use regexps at all when you're really trying to do exact matches on strings)

Comment: Thanks ED , base d on you explanation I modified my command to  awk -F":" -v M="Mary Jane" -v A="Runs" -v S="Sleeps" 'BEGIIN{OFS=":"}{ print gensub("("M"):"A,"\\1:"S,1)}'   and I have a question that in gensub  why have you kept   A in the search pattern outside the double quotes and S in the replacement pattern outside the quotes ? Shouldn't they be enclosed in double quotes , but when I do so I don't get the desired result. Please advise

Comment: Double quotes delimit literal strings. Variables do not expand within literal strings because, well, they are literal. If you write `A="x"; print A` you get out the value of variable `A`, i.e. `"x"`, but if you write `A="x"; print "A"` then you get out the value of the literal string `"A"` which is, of course, `"A"`. The use of strings and variables in the context of dynamic regexps is no different. `$0 ~ "foo"A` matches the string `"foox"`, the string produced by the concatenation of `"foo"` with the contents of variable `A`, while `$0 ~ "fooA"` matches the string `"fooA"`.

Comment: but you have double quoted M inside gensub("("M"):"A,"\\1:"S,1)} how is M getting expanded in there ?

Comment: Count the double quotes. Is `M` REALLY inside double quotes?

Comment: What I am trying to understand is why can't we write it like  gensub((M):A,"\\1:"S,1) why do this doesn't expand M and why do we need "("M"):"  in there ?

Comment: That does expand M but the first argument to `gensub()` is a regexp and that can be a literal regexp like `/.../` or a dynamic regexp `"..."` or `var` or `"..."var` or similar so then what do `(` and `):` mean in that context? They aren't inside double quotes, they aren't a variable name, and they aren't inside regexp delimiters (`/`s). `(` and `)` can be used to group sub-expressions during string concatenation or other operations so syntactically those have a meaning in that context (but not the meaning you want). The `:` on the other hand is simply a syntax error in that context.

Comment: The point is that if you aren't using a regexp literal as that first arg to `gensub()` then the ONLY alternative is something that evaluates to a string as that constitutes a dynamic regexp. It's GOT to be a regexp. If you write `(M):A` then that is simply not an expression that evaluates to a string (and so not a dynamic regexp) because while `(M)` means the same as just `M` in that context, there's a literal `:` in there that has no place in string concatenation.Try just writing `var="foo""bar"` then `var=("foo")"bar"` then `var=("foo"):"bar"` to see when it fails with a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks you so much Ed that is well explained.

Comment: I tried using a variable defined  in BEGIN in gensub and that also seems to be working fine e.g. `gawk 'BEGIN{a="Nation"}NR%2{print  gensub(/(Hello) (World)/,"\\1"" "a,"g",$0)}'` , ( adding this comment for my own personal reference)

Comment: `"\\1"" "a` = `"\\1 "a`

Comment: Ed, you have Eagle eyes!